# Why do loc and iloc work differently for slicing rows of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want a DataFrame where the top rows of one column (called 'cat') have value "LOW", the mid and bottom parts of the frame will have values "MID" and "HI". So, for a frame of 1,200 rows, the value counts for the `cat` columns should result in:

```
LOW    400
MID    400
HI     400
```

This should be easy. But, apparently it is not really. To no avail I tried to select and change the bottom rows using `df.loc[-400:,["cat"]] = "HI"`

But, this approach does work for the top-rows: `df.loc[:399,["cat"]] = "LOW"`

The sample below shows a working example, and note that it requires both `loc` and `iloc`. Is this where pandas can improve?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([1200, 4]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df["cat"] = "MID"
df.loc[:399,["cat"]] = "LOW"
df.iloc[-400:,-1] = "HI"  # The -1 selects the last column ('cat') - not ideal.
df.cat.value_counts()
```

Comment: you could also only use `.iloc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `cat` if want select by positions by `iloc` - need positions of index and columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([1200, 4]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df["cat"] = "MID"

df.iloc[:400,df.columns.get_loc('cat')] = "LOW"
df.iloc[-400:,df.columns.get_loc('cat')] = "HI"
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.columns.get_loc('cat'))
4
```

Alternative is use `loc` for select by labels - then need select `400` values of index by indexing:

```
df.loc[df.index[:400],"cat"] = "LOW"
df.loc[df.index[-400:],"cat"] = "HI"

a = df.cat.value_counts()
print (a)
MID    400
HI     400
LOW    400
Name: cat, dtype: int64
```

Another ways for set 400 values use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) or set values by repeat of lists:

```
df["cat"] =  np.array(["LOW", "MID", "HI"]).repeat(400)

df["cat"] =  ["LOW"] * 400 + ["MID"] * 400 +  ["HI"] * 400
#thanks  @Quickbeam2k1
df = df.assign(cat = ['LOW']*400 + ['MID']*400 + ['HIGH']*400 )
```

Comment: another way: `df.assign(cat = ['LOW']*400 + ['MID']*400 + ['HIGH']*400 )`

Comment: @jezraels, I think, you should change your first solution to only use `.iloc`. I think using both accessors is what bothers the OP

Comment: This is excellent, I like the one that uses np.array + repeat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question if pandas can improve here: 
I the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)  it's clearly stated what loc is doing:

> .loc is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array. .loc will raise KeyError when the items are not found.

so -400 is simply not a label in your index. Thus the behavior is as intended.

What one often wants is and accessor for iloc based row access and loc based column access. But for this, the `.get_loc`-function comes into play.

You could also use the deprecated `.ix`-indexer. However, its behavior caused some confusion. She examples and methods using the `.loc` and `.iloc` accessors [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated).
Essentially, @Jezrael's solution are also found in the link above.

To summarize: Pandas had a solution to your problem in place, but it confused users. So in order to provide a more consistent API it was decided to remove that feature in the future